# What's the lifetime of HttpContext.Current?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading

I'm using HttpContext.Current.User to store some data about the client when the request is received.

I'm afraid that I might run into NullObjectReferenceException when HttpContext.Current is nulled unexpectedly and I'm trying to extract data from HttpContext.Current.User

The docomentation says about HttpContext.Current, that it:

> Gets or sets the HttpContext object for the current HTTP request.

What are the cases where HttpContext.Current could be set to null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `null` when your [scope is not part of a Request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19511677/56145).

Examples include:

- [`Application_Start`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19509800/56145)
- Or a background (non-Request) thread doing some other work.

If you're doing these things inside of a request you should be fine.

If you're using a background thread, or hooking some other part of aspnet which doesn't have the Request context then the static `HttpContext` might not be for you. There are other Request and Response contexts as well as Controller contexts which might be better. You should also [consider injecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43322447/inject-applicationuser-in-asp-net-core-mvc) these [things using a Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877712/asp-net-mvc-httpcontext-and-dependency-injection) or, in the case where you don't know the execution context, [wrap getting the user in an interface](http://rion.io/2016/01/04/accessing-identity-info-using-dependency-injection-in-net-5/) so you can deal with these context scenarios more cleanly.

[This world is different in aspnet Core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57908890/56145) so I'm assuming you're referring to aspnet Framework.

Comment: And also once the HTTP request is complete, i.e. once you have returned a response.

Comment: And there's a bug (not sure resolved yet or not) in ASP.NET core where it is sometimes null in `async` methods when execution resumes after `await`. Let me see if I can find the link on GitHub for that.